# Create a multiple screen android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application that will work on every android phone or tablet device and it will only support **portrait**.

Reading [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) I see a table with a lot of screen sizes and densities.

**How many layouts do I need? One for every screen size and density?**

I think I only need four: one for small, normal, large and x-large.

Comment: Actually, It depends on your requirement. If you want to support Landscape orientation also, then you have to create layout for layout-land, layout-large-land and many more.

Comment: It will support only portrait.

Comment: Usually it's enough to supply just one layout. If your going to support really small or really large devices you might want to try it and provide layouts for those.

Comment: I also suggest you to go with only one layout and design with independent criteria.. For support multiple screen  use different size drawable..

Comment: +1 i would go with @user370305 => Create one layout and provide images for different screens and densities.

Comment: @user370305 I'm doing it now it that way and on my 7' tablet it doesn't look like my HTC Desire. So, I need more than one layout.

Comment: Testing the layout in Eclipse I have a list with different screens sizes. I test it with Nexus one and with 3.4 FWQVGA and it looks different. By the way I use dp units.

Comment: If you follow **Android UI Design** guidelines and use all drawables with different sizes and densities also use **dip** for dimension of hard-coded layouts then I don't think so you need all different layouts. The main purpose of those are in if you have to different modes support like, portrait or landscape, but in your case you have supported only portarait.

Comment: @user370305 But the same layout looks different on a HTC Desire and on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7. I use dp units.

Comment: Look at http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626248/same-layout-looks-different-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab Here you can find a layout that looks different on a HTC Desire and on a Galaxy Tab 7.7.

Answer (score 1):

you basically need four. But if you you want you application to behave different according to *different screen sizes* **AND** *different orientations*, you should use:

```
/layout-port         > for medium layout portrait
/layout-land         > for medium layout landscape
/layout-xlarge-port  > for xlarge layout portrait
/layout-xlarge-land  > for xlarge layout landscape
```

etc.

Comment: @CodersParadise. I need four and also need ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi images, isn't it?

Comment: as @PareshMayani considered, you wont need all that different layouts or different image densities. these only make your application look beautiful in different screen sizes. if you put images with different densities android will choose one of them according to the device. if you have only one density image (e.g mdpi) android will use that image always (also for different density screens).

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided:

```
By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. 
In most cases, this works fine.
```

Therefore the general rule is to use Density Independent Pixels (dips) for size definitions in your layout xmls leaving the rest to be handled by the operating system. Doing so you just have the only layout for all range of devices.

Making separate layouts is not really common practice. Only when you have images that can't be stretched is that really the recommended way. In that case, splitting the graphics based on the size and density of the screen can solve your problem anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like this part: "In most cases, this works fine."
The same layout looks different on a HTC Desire and on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7.

Comment: Same layout generally looks the same on different devices including the tablets if you follow [Best Practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence). That's the whole point of my answer. You just might consider different sized drawables for your application based on screen density.

Comment: Yes, I have different images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and x-hdpi.

Answer (score 1):

One layout is enough for device up to large density , if you also want to implement layout for x-large screen size then you need to make another layout,
 just  get the images as per ldpi , mpdi and hdpi , place them the relative folders , 
create layout using appropriate layout weights give full size to backgrounds like fill parent and exact size of buttons

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".55"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/goBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_btn" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Forget Paaword"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".55"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hombutton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/home1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/usernametext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5" android:imeOptions="actionDone">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Email Id"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailtextfp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:inputType="textEmailSubject" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginbuttonfp"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn" android:text="Ok" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn" android:text="Cancel" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7 has a x-large screen size?

Comment: though i have not worked with tabs yet but , i think it should come under x-larger as its display is quite larger  7.7” [2] 1280×800 (WXGA)  Super AMOLED Plus

Comment: Ok, I will add a x-large layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool that allows you to scale/adjust your layouts for tablets and small screen devices and made a blog post about it here: http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

Basically, defining your layouts in dp units for one size is not enough if you want your app to fit on all devices and tablets, since there's four different "density-buckets".

This tool will allow your layouts to be converted into fitting these density buckets from a default baseline.

Hope it helps.